# .htaccess not working on some files

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

My `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
# Prevent .htaccess files from being viewed
<Files ".ht*">
  Require all denied
</Files>

# Deny access to files with extensions
<Files ".*\.md">
  Require all denied
</Files>

# Allow to get error log
<Files "linked-error.log">
  Require all denied
  Require ip 10.10.15.1
</Files>
```

The first two parts is working as expected, I cannot access to those `.ht*` and `.md` files.

The last part seems broken, because I can access the file `linked-error.log` from anywhere. It is a soft link file to today's error log.

My html document directory is like:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 1029 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     9809 linked-error.log -> /home/project/log/error.log
-rwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 2762 index.php
```

I had already restart apache server `sudo service apache2 restart`.

#### Update:

If I delete the soft link and copy the file `linked-error.log` to website root directly, the blocking role still does not work.

Comment: Is `linked-error.log` in the same directory as `.htaccess`? Is Apache behind a reverse proxy? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Did you try to turn the rules around?